# How to get loop bounds in LLVM?

Tags: loops, llvm, bounds, nest

I want to get the loop bounds by using LLVM API. Here is the part of the code as follows. I don't know whether it is right to get the bounds. So, is there any other situation that I haven't thought about?

```
typedef std::vector<Loop*> LoopNest;
typedef std::vector<const Value*> LoopNestBounds;
...
void getLoopNestBounds(const LoopNest &Nest, LoopNestBounds &LBounds) {
    ScalarEvolution &SE = getAnalysis<ScalarEvolution>();
    for (unsigned d = 0, n = Nestsize(); d != n; ++d) {
        if (SE.hasLoopInvariantBackedgeTakenCount(Nest[d])) {
            const SCEV *C = SE.getBackedgeTakenCount(Nest[d]);
            const SCEVConstant *CC = dyn_cast<const SCEVConstant>(C);
            LBounds.push_back(CC->getValue());
            errs() << CC->getValue()->getValue() << " iterations\n";
        }
        else {
            LBounds.push_back(0);
            errs() << "---- 0 iterations for the nest ----" << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the version of LLVM is 3.0.

Comment: Why don't you just use `getSmallConstantTripCount` function from ScalarEvolution Analysis?

Comment: Oh, I don't know ScalarEvolution Analysis has such a function!Function getSmallConstantTripCount is easier. Thanks~